# How can I share activity (Reading a book) Facebook cannot find?

Tags: facebook, status

I like to share review/recommendations on books I read and other activities via "Feeling/Activity" post option.

Problem is sometimes there is no entry for the book I read (or other activities).
Here for example I would like to share that I am reading book "Mimi a Liza 2", but there is no entry for it.

[image: Set activity - reading a book "Mimi a Liza 2"]

There is no option to add new book and activity will not add unless I select from the given list.
I did not find any "Add activity" or "Add book" options.

When I add whole name of book, posting button is still disabled, and when I add status text it will allow me to post, but result is without activity part:

[image: Added whole name of book to post]

[image: Created post, without activity section]

Is it possible to add activities that Facebook cannot find?

Comment: What did happen if you write "Mimi a Liza 2"  and save it instead of selecting from options? Is it not letting you to write there?

Comment: @serenesat nothing happens - empty post cannot be added and non empty post will be posted withou activity. I updated question with this test.

Comment: Wait, how did you even get it to say "Reading" next to where you are entering text? It makes me type over where it says "What's on your mind" and doesn't offer "Reading" as an option!

Comment: @Michael you have to pick "Feeling/Activity" first

Answer (score 0):

I know. It’s a pain. The only way seems to be to create a page yourself for that book.
And then you can use it in your post.