# How do I share a book I am reading on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, status

It's apparently possible to share a book I am reading on Facebook. The question is asked [How to share a book that Facebook cannot find](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/142976/how-can-i-share-activity-reading-a-book-facebook-cannot-find).  But I can't even figure out how to share a book at all!  Their screen shot shows a "Reading" option when it asks what is on your mind.  I do not see that.[image]

This pops up when I try to click on the "What's on your mind" bar at the top of my Posts. If I click on the "..." it offers things like "Photo/Video", "Tag People", etc.  Nothing about books

On the other hand, if I go to my profile page under Books it offers me no way to add books.  Supposedly there are supposed to be "Add" buttons for Books, Movies and other things, but there are none.

So how to I share a book that I have read or am reading?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the book list they have is kind of weak and if your book is not in the list, you cannot add it. But here is how. Create a new status, choose feeling/activity, choose reading then search for your book.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It didn't occur to me that feeling/activity would lead to the choice of reading!